# How to use numerical variables in makefile?

Tags: makefile, dd

I'm trying to concatenate a series of files, with paddings of zeros so that each of them take up multiples of 512 byte, and forms a floppy image using `dd`.

I imagined the makefile would look like this:

```
CurrentLocation := 1
build:
    dd if=bootloader of=result bs=1474560 count=1 conv=sync # writes sector 0, guaranteed to be 512B
    dd if=file1 of=result obs=512 conv=sync,notrunc # writes file1 
    # get file size using 'stat' command and convert to sectors
    dd if=file2 of=result obs=512 conv=sync,notrunc seek=#CurrentLocation+filesize
    ... and so on ...
```

But I couldn't figure out how to do it (or is there a better way to do it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what numerics you are intending to do. However, I think this example will provide you with what you need:

```
SHELL = /usr/bin/env bash

CurrentLocation := 1
build:
        ((sum = $(CurrentLocation) + 2)); echo $$sum
```

Here I make use of the `((...))` bash syntax, which can handle integer arithmetic. Also note how I escape the Make variable `CurrentLocation` and the bash variable `sum` differently. Also note that I define and reference `sum` in the same line. This is important, as Make runs each line in a different subshell, meaning that `sum` is not defined on the next line. Finally, I found that I had to explicitly tell Make to use the bash shell using e.g. `SHELL = /usr/bin/env bash`.

Note that you cannot update the Make variable `CurrentLocation` using this technique.

Comment: I'm thinking about updating the literal 2 using file properties. Those files may span more than two sectors, and I want to use code to compute that instead of hardcoding them, and update `CurrentLocation` after each `dd` call, so that all files take up contiguous sectors.

Comment: You can update the literal `2` if you keep everything in the same subshell, meaning on the same line. You cannot however update the Make variable `CurrentLocation`. Try `current=0; size=$$(stat --printf='%s' file1); ((sum = $$current + $$size)); echo $$sum`. It would however be prettier to just put all of this in a proper bash script and call this script from the makefile.